# Why can't I debug a Delphi XE7 Android app on my device?

Tags: android, delphi, adb, delphi-xe7, android-debug

I am able to debug on an Android Emulator, but when I want to debug on `ASUS Memorypad 7` it doesn't work.

After I hit cancel it gives the following message:

```
Unable to start gdbserver on port '64311'. Port is already in use.
```

I have changed the port several times in the Run parameters, but it still gives the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I needed to get another device.
I'm using Huawei's MediaPad M1 8.0 now and that works after I installed HiSuite.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting everything first. Then follow Embarcadero`s guide:

> Unable to start gdbserver on port : Port is already in use

where  is the port number being used by the Android gdbserver:

Power off or restart your Android device and then run your application again.

Choose another debug port:

Select Run > Parameters and enter the following in the Parameters field:

```
        -debugport=<n> where <n> is an alternate debug port, such as 54321.
```

Then click OK.

[Link Reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/RunAndroidTargetFailedHelpPage)

Comment: As I said in the description of my ask, I have done that several times already, yet I still get the same message.

Comment: I restarted my tablet, Delphi and my computer several times, but I still get that message.

Comment: @Machado Why you ever got a downvote for the right answer, I'll never know.

Comment: @nolaspeaker people are strange