# Unable to debug Android Application Delphi Seattle

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I'll run my program (Delphi Seattle, Galaxy Note 3), it compiles and launches within the phone. Meanwhile Delphi is stuck on the compile window stating: "Launching com.embarcadero.DriverApp".

Same exact thing happens with an out-of-the-box program, so I don't think it's my source.

It won't stop on any breakpoints and I can't step through the code.

When I hit Cancel it says "Unable to start gdbserver on port '64311'. Port is already in use.

I've tried setting my install location to internalOnly from [here](https://community.embarcadero.com/answers/android-deploy-to-h-w-error-unable-to-start-gdbserver-on-port-64311)

I've tried changing the port with parameters (-debugport) from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429137/why-cant-i-debug-a-delphi-xe7-android-app-on-my-device)

I've tried rebooting the phone, Delphi, and computer multiple times.

I've tried updating the SDK as mentioned [here](http://www.vr-online.ru/blog/unable-start-gdbserver-port-64311-pod-android-reshenie-problemy-9414)

I've followed the ideas from [here](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10365) with no success. They ended up asking me to post a new Issue.

Finally, I have updated my USB drivers for the phone.

Edit: I took the exact source code and tried it from my home computer. It worked.

Comment: And the difference between the home computer and the computer elsewhere is.... what? Different OS? Different device driver version for the device in question?

Comment: If it comes to it you can perform "agricultural" debugging by using lots of calls to `Log.d` from FMX.Types.pas in order to track progress through your app without the use of a debugger at all. You can see the output of these messages in logcat, visible by running $(ANDROIDSDK)\tools\monitor.bat. This permits you to dump mesasges about progress through code and values of expressions, and thereby still work on your project even with no real debugger available to use.

Comment: @blong - The OS is the same, but I'll check the drivers. Update: I was able to get my tablet working on the problem computer.

Comment: Any clue as to the source of the issue?

Comment: @blong - Sorry for the delay. I've finished checking. Both computers are Win 10 Pro, same version. Both are running Seattle no updates. Both are using the same USB drivers and version. I've been able to get into the Quality Portal and have supplied additional information here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/issues/?filter=-2

Comment: FYI that's not a link to a QP bug report. That's a link to a filtered view for a logged in user

Comment: Thanks, they ended up having me create a fresh issue: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16960

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Easy solution: You should not use the "Application store" configuration in combination with Debug build configuration!